# %{__python} percent sign curly braces variable in cobbler spec file

Tags: python, shell, redhat, specifications

I'm trying to understand how the cobbler spec file works.

The first lines are:

`%{!?python_sitelib: %define python_sitelib %(%{__python} -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()")}
%{!?pyver: %define pyver %(%{__python} -c "import sys ; print sys.version[:3]" || echo 0)}`

I guess my main question is where does the `%{__python}` variable come from?
And if I change it to `%{__python26}`, I get the following error `sh: line 0: fg: no job control`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer in the Fedora Packaging documentation [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging%3aPython)

Basically, `%{__python}` is a predefined macro.

To define my own (to point to python2.6), this is required at the top of spec file:

`%{!?__python26: %global __python26 /usr/bin/python2.6}`